# Video upload issue php mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, file, video, upload

I've been having difficulty with creating a video uploader using php, mySQL, and HTML/CSS. I'm still fairly new to php and mySQL but I have a basic understanding of the two. I followed a tutorial and slightly modified it. However when I try to upload the video file, it returns;

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/testVideo.mov): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/VarcFiles/upload.php on line 24
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpwWU1M4' to 'uploads/testVideo.mov' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/VarcFiles/upload.php on line 24

Below these warnings would be the video, which isn't playing.

The database table, video, which stores the video is working though.

**Note:** The, include "config.php"; already connects the database with the variable $link.

```
<?php

include "config.php";

extract($_POST);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST['upd'])){
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "mpeg-4" && $imageFileType != "mov"
&& $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "mpeg-ps" 
&& $imageFileType != "flv" && $imageFileType != "3gpp" && $imageFileType != "webm") {
echo "Desculpa, só aceitamos MOV, MPEG-4, MP4, AVI, WMV, MPEG-PS, FLV, 3GPP, & WebM";
}
else{
$video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO video(video_name) VALUES('$video_path')");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);

echo "Carregado ";
}

}
//display all uploaded video
if('disp'){
$query=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM video");

while($all_video=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>

 <video width="300" height="200" controls>
 <source src="uploads/<?php echo $all_video['video_name']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video> 

<?php } } ?>
```

Next is the HTML file,

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Selecione um vídeo para enviar:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Carregar um vídeo" name="upd"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Exibir vídeo" name="disp"/>
</form>
```

The tutorial I was following is here,
https://www.phptpoint.com/upload-video-in-php/

Comment: The message is pretty clear. The web server process does not have write access to the `uploads` directory.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, shouldn't these two lines cover for that? $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

Comment: That has nothing to do with file permissions. Those statements simply set a target directory.

Comment: I'm confused as to how I would get write access to the uploads directory. I found out the problem is in this line, move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
I tried modifying it based on what I looked up regarding this issue, however I haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Permissions have nothing at all to do with your code. You need to check the directory permissions on your server. If you have a hosting plan most of them offer a way to view the files and directories and include a way to check the permissions of same.

Comment: I'm using a local server with xampp and for mySQL I'm using PopSQL. So would I need to check the permissions for both or just for xampp?

Comment: Again, nothing to do with your code or SQL, it is simply a permissions problem in your operating system. Read up on how to check and change directory permissions on whatever OS you are using.

Comment: Ok, now I'm understanding. Thanks for the help!